# Partitioning in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I've been trying to find the median number of times an account (person) is seen (appt_id) by a provider (provider_code) in a given period. The attached SQL doesn't seen to be capturing all of the provider_codes and I can't figure out why. Desired outcome is that all provider_code are listed with a median number.

*I don't have access to MS SQL Server 2012 or Newer - yes we are way behind the times and yes it does make life much more difficult.

[image: Sample_data]

```
SELECT
   provider_code, office_location,
  CONVERT(INT, count(account)) AS Median

FROM
(
   SELECT
      office_location,provider_code,
   account,appt_date,dept_code,appt_status,appt_class,
      ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER (
         PARTITION BY office_location,provider_code
         ORDER BY account ASC) as RowAsc, 

      ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER (
         PARTITION BY office_location,provider_code
         ORDER BY account DESC) as RowDesc

   FROM appointments_view WITH(NOLOCK)


WHERE account IS NOT NULL AND appt_date BETWEEN '1/1/17' /*24 month prior*/ AND '1/1/19' 


 ) X


WHERE 
   RowAsc IN (RowDesc, RowDesc - 1, RowDesc + 1)


GROUP BY office_location,provider_code
ORDER BY office_location,provider_code
```

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag.  The code is clearly SQL Server.  The median of *what*.  Sample data, desired results, and a better explanation of the logic you want would all help.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Why both `MySQL` and `T-SQL`? MySQL didn't even have `ROW_NUMBER()` until the very latest version, 8.0. BTW the date strings are definitely .... unconventional and prone to conversion errors. Two-digit years are particularly bad.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the median for US houses during WW1 perhaps? It's 100 years after WW1 ended after all.

Comment: what is this supposed to do? WHERE 
   RowAsc IN (RowDesc, RowDesc - 1, RowDesc + 1)

Comment: I added a sample data set.  I'm tying to get the median number of sessions an accounts(people) is seen (appt_id) by a Provider (provider_code) in a give amount of time.

Comment: You need to order by _count_ inside your inner query... which means you need another  sub-query.

Comment: I get an error when i try to add ORDER BY to my inner query. clause invalid in functions,derived tables, sub queries...

Comment: Your query will return 1 if the number of accounts is odd and 2 otherwise. Is that what you call "median"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a median you could use the window function [PERCENTILE_CONT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql) or [PERCENTILE_DISC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-disc-transact-sql)
*(MS Sql Server 2012+)*

**Example snippet:**

```
declare @Appointments table (
 appt_id int primary key identity(4046100,1), 
 appt_date date not null default GetDate(), 
 account int not null, 
 provider_code varchar(10) not null, 
 office_location char(3) not null default 'REN', 
 appt_class char(3) not null 
 );

insert into @Appointments (appt_date, account, provider_code, appt_class) values
('2019-02-01',100001,'FOO1','IND'),('2019-02-01',100002,'FOO1','IND'),('2019-02-01',100002,'FOO1','PSY'),('2019-02-01',100002,'FOO1','IND'),
('2019-02-01',100002,'FOO1','IND'),('2019-02-01',100003,'FOO1','IND'),('2019-02-01',100003,'FOO1','IND'),('2019-02-01',100003,'FOO1','IND');

select provider_code, office_location, MAX(MedianContTotalAppointments) AS MedianApt
from
(
    select provider_code, office_location, account
    , count(appt_id) as TotalAppointments
    , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY count(appt_id)) OVER (PARTITION BY provider_code, office_location) AS MedianContTotalAppointments
    -- , PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY count(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY provider_code, office_location) AS MedianDiscTotalAppointments
    from @Appointments
    where account IS NOT NULL 
      and appt_date BETWEEN cast('2017-02-01' as date) AND cast('2019-02-01' as date)
    group by provider_code, office_location, account
) q
group by provider_code, office_location
order by provider_code, office_location;
```

**Returns:**

```
provider_code   office_location     MedianApt
FOO1            REN                 3
```

In a MS Sql Server version before 2012, then this example snippet might work:

```
declare @Appointments table (
 appt_id int primary key identity(4046100,1), 
 appt_date date not null default GetDate(), 
 account int not null, 
 provider_code varchar(10) not null, 
 office_location char(3) not null default 'REN', 
 appt_class char(3) not null 
 );

insert into @Appointments (appt_date, account, provider_code, appt_class) values
 ('2019-02-01',100001,'FOO1','IND'),('2019-02-01',100002,'FOO1','IND'),('2019-02-01',100002,'FOO1','PSY'),('2019-02-01',100002,'FOO1','IND')
,('2019-02-01',100002,'FOO1','IND'),('2019-02-01',100003,'FOO1','IND'),('2019-02-01',100003,'FOO1','IND'),('2019-02-01',100003,'FOO1','IND')
--,('2019-02-01',100004,'FOO1','IND'),('2019-02-01',100004,'FOO1','IND')
;

select provider_code, office_location, AVG(TotalAppointments) AS MedianApt
from
(
    select provider_code, office_location, account
    , COUNT(appt_id) as TotalAppointments
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY provider_code, office_location ORDER BY COUNT(appt_id) ASC) AS rn
    , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY provider_code, office_location) AS cnt
    from @Appointments
    where account IS NOT NULL 
      and appt_date BETWEEN cast('2017-02-01' as date) AND cast('2019-02-01' as date)
    group by provider_code, office_location, account
) q
where rn in (FLOOR((cnt+1)*0.5), CEILING((cnt+1)*0.5))
group by provider_code, office_location
order by provider_code, office_location;
```

Comment: I think that's what 'm looking for put how would I insert the existing data? I'm working with a table on thousands of entries so manually inputting isn't an option.

Comment: It's just a test script that uses a table variable for demonstration.  So take the query and replace `@Appointments` by your tablename.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm sure it will work but apparently my company doesn't have and SQL version that current enough for the Percentile_cont function

Comment: Oh I see. Well I thought that these days most would have at least a MS Sql Server 2012 or higher.

Comment: I works wonderfully, Thanks so much for sticking with it and coming up with an answer!!

Comment: Nice. Btw, hardcoding the dates isn't always needed.  Try to guess what this returns `select dateadd(year,-2,dateadd(day,1,eomonth(GetDate(),-1))) as twoyearago, eomonth(GetDate(),-1) as prevmonthlastday`. Oh wait, scrap that, EOMONTH is 2012 stuff.  I said nothing!

Comment: We are working on a lot of internal updates so hopefully the 2012 stuff will apply to me soon.